# Search and Replace RANGE Pattern

Tags: html, regex, bash, awk, sed

Imagine multiple HTML files were merged with all the leftover formatting, tags, etc--never mind *why*--What tools should one use to search from the beginning lines of the subsequently merged html files, i.e. `<!doctype html>...` to the beginning of the `<h1>` header? That range pattern should be replaced by a horizontal rule instead.

```
---END OF PREV MERGED FILE---
---BEGIN SEARCH/REPLACE HERE---
<!doctype html>
        <!--[if !IE]>
        <html class="no-js non-ie" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE 7 ]>
        <html class="no-js ie7" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE 8 ]>
        <html class="no-js ie8" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE 9 ]>
---HEAD,META,ETC---
---END SEARCH/REPLACE HERE---
<h1>TITLE OF NEXT MERGED FILE</h1>
```

I'm not sure if `sed` and `awk` are the wrong tools for this, but something along the line of similar tools/solutions is preferred.

---

**Input**

```
<li><strong>email_from = root@localhost</strong>, <strong>email_to = root</strong>, <strong>email_host = localhost</strong> defines respectively when the message is a mail the originator&#8217;s email address, the recipient&#8217;s
 email address and the host to which the mail is sent.<strong><br />
 30658  </strong></li>
 30659  </ul>
 30660  <p>Source: <a title="http://linuxaria.com/howto/enabling-automatic-updates-in-centos-7-and-rhel-7" href="http://linuxaria.com/howto/enabling-automatic-updates-in-centos-7-and-rhel-7">Linuxaria&#8217;s website</a>.</p>
 30661                                                                          </div><!-- end of .post-entry -->

 30662

 30663  <div class="post-edit"></div>
 30664                                                          </div><!-- end of #post-4116 -->
 30665
 30666




 30667          <!doctype html>
 30668          <!--[if !IE]>
 30669          <html class="no-js non-ie" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <![endif]-->
 30670          <!--[if IE 7 ]>
 30671          <html class="no-js ie7" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <![endif]-->
 30672          <!--[if IE 8 ]>
 30673          <html class="no-js ie8" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <![endif]-->
 30674          <!--[if IE 9 ]>
 30675          <html class="no-js ie9" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <![endif]-->
 30676          <!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
 30677  <html class="no-js" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <!--<![endif]-->
 30678          <head>

 30679                  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
 30680                  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 30681                  <title>something something</title>

 30682                  <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"/>
 30683                  <link rel="pingback" href="www.example.com"/>

 30684
 30685          <h1 class="entry-title post-title">Something Something</h1>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<li><strong>email_from = root@localhost</strong>, <strong>email_to = root</strong>, <strong>email_host = localhost</strong> defines respectively when the message is a mail the originator&#8217;s email address, the recipient&#8217;s
     email address and the host to which the mail is sent.<strong><br />
     30658  </strong></li>
     30659  </ul>
     30660  <p>Source: <a title="http://linuxaria.com/howto/enabling-automatic-updates-in-centos-7-and-rhel-7" href="http://linuxaria.com/howto/enabling-automatic-updates-in-centos-7-and-rhel-7">Linuxaria&#8217;s website</a>.</p>
     30661                                                                          </div><!-- end of .post-entry -->

     30662

     30663  <div class="post-edit"></div>
     30664                                                          </div><!-- end of #post-4116 -->


    <hr />




     30685          <h1 class="entry-title post-title">Something Something</h1>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the man pages. `sed` is used for search and replace and supports regular expressions. `awk` is more for working with columnar text files. I think you want `sed`.

Comment: yea, the problem is that with `sed` I don't know the exact line numbers; with awk, html formatting is a PITA; so I'm not sure how to proceed even after looking at the *numerous* other examples that are one, two, or three degrees away from what I need.

Comment: `sed` doesn't require line numbers, it would be something like: `sed 's/pattern/replace/g' file.html > edited.html` The tricky part is figuring out the pattern, which might just take some trial and error

Comment: Maybe the search/replace in `vim` might be better suited, since it's only one big file.  As for `sed`, I need to *search* the RANGE and *replace* with a different RANGE.  Not search word/regex replace line/word with something.

Comment: Is the snippet you posted the sample input or expected output? In any case - post both the testable sample input and the precise expected output given that input and clearly state which is which. Keep in mind we are looking for something that not only clarifies your problem but which we can test a potential solution against.

Comment: Why not just a simple Find: `<!doctype html>[\S\s]*?(?=\s*<h1>)` and Replace: `<hr />`

Comment: @sln Is that within Vim or from the command line? command line is preferred, but I'll settle for Vim until I find a better solution.

Comment: Don't know Vim, but its fairly standard extended regex.

Comment: Should be able to be done using _sed_, probably with the Perl flag. I don't know the sed command line though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
awk '/<!doctype html>/{f=1;print "    <hr />";} /<h1 class=/{f=0;} !f' input >output
```

#### How it works

- `/<!doctype html>/{f=1;print "    <hr />";}`

  When we reach a line that contains `<!doctype html>`, this sets flag `f` to `1` to signal that we should stop printing.  Then, we print the horizontal rule.
- `/<h1 class=/{f=0;}`

  When we reach a line that contains `<h1 class=`. set flag `f` to `0` to signal that we can continue printing.
- `!f`

  This causes the current line to be printed if `f` is `0`.

  In more detail, `!f` is a *condition*.  When the condition is true, awk performs an action.  Since no action was specified, awk will perform its default action which is to print the line.  `!` is awk's symbol for negation.  So, when `f` is false (0), then `!f` is true and the line is printed.

#### Keeping the first doctype tag

Suppose that we want to remove all doctype tags **except** for the first.  In that case:

```
awk '/<!doctype html>/{count++; if (count>1){f=1; print "    <hr />";}} /<h1 class=/{f=0;} !f' input
```

This works by adding another variable, `count`, which tracks how many doctype tags we have seen.  The flag `f` is set to `1` only after we have seen more than one doctype tag.

To demonstrate the above, let's use this input file:

```
$ cat input2
miscellaneous stuff
30667          <!doctype html>
30668          something
30669          <h1 class="entry-title post-title">Something Something</h1>
More stuff
30667          <!doctype html>
30668          something 2
30669          <h1 class="entry-title post-title">Something Something</h1>
Still More stuff
30667          <!doctype html>
30668          something 3
30669          <h1 class="entry-title post-title">Something Something</h1>
Stuff at end
```

The output produced by the command is:

```
$ awk '/<!doctype html>/{count++; if (count>1){f=1; print "    <hr />";}} /<h1 class=/{f=0;} !f' input2
miscellaneous stuff
30667          <!doctype html>
30668          something
30669          <h1 class="entry-title post-title">Something Something</h1>
More stuff
    <hr />
30669          <h1 class="entry-title post-title">Something Something</h1>
Still More stuff
    <hr />
30669          <h1 class="entry-title post-title">Something Something</h1>
Stuff at end
```

Comment: Thanks for the `f` flag and thorough explanation. Is that part of the awk language or regex?

Comment: Your welcome.  `f` is just an awk variable.  Unlike sed, awk allows programs to define variables by name and manipulate their values.  We could have chosen any name we liked.

Comment: Seems I spoke too soon; Is there a way to tell `awk` to skip over the first result at the very beginning of the file? I recall something about the `BEGIN` option, but in this case it would have to be the opposite of that.

Comment: @ILMostro_7 I added code to the answer to keep the first doctype tag.  Have a look.